# How to check a string starts with a substring or not in java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to check a string which starts with `http://` or not. How can I do that without loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(str.indexOf("http://")==0)`?

Comment: Your first stop should always be the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

use `public boolean startsWith(String prefix)` in [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) API

eg : `boolean isStartsWith = YOUR_STRING.startsWith("http://");`

```
String tst = "http://web.com";
System.out.print(tst.startsWith("http://")); //prints true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can basically use the simplest method... i.e methods provided with the String API..

```
public boolean startsWith(String prefix, int toffset)
                 or
public boolean startsWith(String prefix)
```

For example :

```
String str = new String("http://www.google.com");
str.startsWith("http://");
```

It returns true if the condition is met else will return false.