# Java while loop | true if test value returns exeption error

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, try-catch

I'm working on a project, and I need to skip all lines that begin with '"'. I have this code:

```
 String line = reader.readLine();
 boolean containsChar;
 try { containsChar = line.charAt(0) != '\"'; }
 catch (Exception ex) { containsChar = true; }
 while (line != null && containsChar) {
     line = reader.readLine();
     try { containsChar = line.charAt(0) != '\"'; }
     catch (Exception ex) { containsChar = true; }
 }
```

I used to have a short piece of code, but that would detect any line which contains a '"' anywhere in the line:

```
while (line != null && !line.contains("\"")) { line = reader.readLine(); }
```

I had a short way of doing it, but it is possible for a line to be empty. In this case the code returns an exception:

```
while (line != null && line.charAt(0) != '\"') { line = reader.readLine(); }
```

Question:
Is it possible to have code similar to the code below, where the try-catch is inside of the while test?

```
while (line != null && (try { line.charAt(0) != '\"'; }catch (Exception ex) { true; })) { line = reader.readLine(); }
```

Solution:
In one of the comments Thilo gave a solution which works with a char at any index (in this example index 12):

```
( line.length() > 12 && line.charAt(12) == something)
```

Comment: what exception is thrown? why wouldn't you be able to have a try-catch inside a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a string starts with a substring or not in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802234/how-to-check-a-string-starts-with-a-substring-or-not-in-java)

Comment: Also, I suppose [What is IndexOutOfBoundsException? how can i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006317) (although you didn't tell us which exception you're getting)

Comment: @Stultuske An indexOutOfBoundsException. But with any exception I want it to return True. I could do it inside of the loop, but I'm a student and I want to learn short ways to write code. And I quite regularly have a similar problem to this where a test-function can return an exception.

Comment: your method doesn't "return" an Exception, it "throws" one. why not checking for null of line?

Comment: @Stultuske I am already checking if the line is null. But the line is "".
In the comments of the accepted answer I found a good solution. Thilo said: ( line.length() > 12 && line.charAt(12) == something)
This allows me to check any char if it exists :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`String#startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)

```
while (line != null && !line.startsWith(quote))
```

Comment: This indeed helps me in this case. Thank you. But what if, for instance, I want to check for a character at index 12?

Comment: `( line.length() > 12 && line.charAt(12) == something)`

Comment: In Java, you cannot use `try` as an expression. You'd need to move the code into a helper method. Or use Scala :-)